# Entity Framework update object with child collection validation error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I use EF 6.2.0. I have the following entities structure

FacilityGroup

```
public class FacilityGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string InternalNotes { get; set; }

    public virtual List<FacilityInstance> Facilities { get; set; } = new List<FacilityInstance>();
}
```

FacilityInstance

```
public class FacilityInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("IX_FacilityName")]
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string HotelCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual FacilityGroup FacilityGroup { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FacilityGroup))]
    [Index("IX_FacilityGroupId")]
    public int FacilityGroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Update method that is getting called

```
public virtual async Task<OperationStatus> UpdateAsync(T obj, bool requireSave = true)
{
    var operationStatus = new OperationStatus { Status = true };

    try
    {
        DataContext.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        operationStatus = OperationStatus.CreateFromException("Error updating " + typeof(T) + ".", exp);
        //throw;
    }

    if (operationStatus.Status && requireSave)
    {
        operationStatus = await SaveAsync();
    }

    return operationStatus;
}
```

SaveAsync

```
public virtual async Task<OperationStatus> SaveAsync()
{
    var operationStatus = new OperationStatus { Status = true };

    try
    {
        var res = await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        operationStatus.RecordsAffected = res;
        operationStatus.Status = operationStatus.RecordsAffected > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        operationStatus = OperationStatus.CreateFromException("Could not save object.", exp);
        //throw;
    }

    return operationStatus;
}
```

OperationStatus

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Status: {" + nameof(Status) + "}")]
public class OperationStatus
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int RecordsAffected { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public object OperationId { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionStackTrace { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionInnerMessage { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionInnerStackTrace { get; set; }

    public static OperationStatus CreateFromException(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        var status = new OperationStatus
        {
            Status = false,
            Message = message,
            OperationId = null
        };

        if (ex != null)
        {
            status.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
            status.ExceptionStackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
            status.ExceptionInnerMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message;
            status.ExceptionInnerStackTrace = ex.InnerException?.StackTrace;
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call the UpdateAsync for an **existing** `FacilityGroup`, being pulled from the context without changes to the `FacilityGroup.Facilities` collection (which is loaded correctly according to debug) I get validation errors for each item in the collection stating that FacilityGroup is required. I'm trying to change `FacilityGroup.Name`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
[Required]
public virtual FacilityGroup FacilityGroup { get; set; }
```

is completely wrong. `FacilityGroup` is a navigational property, it should not have any attribute besides possibly `[ForeignKey]`. You apply `[Required]` to the property that it's stored in the database, in this case, `FacilityGroupId`. 
However, since `FacilityGroupId` is an `int` (which cannot be `null`), the `[Required]` attribute is not needed.

Also, given that you correctly follow convention over configuration, you should remove that `[ForeignKey]` and end up with this:

```
public virtual FacilityGroup FacilityGroup { get; set; }

[Index("IX_FacilityGroupId")]
public int FacilityGroupId { get; set; }
```

Normally, though, navigational properties are placed at the bottom of the class, after all properties.

Comment: I now get an error `The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.` InvalidOperationException

Comment: What are you passing to the method? That's a very weird issue indicating you aren't doing things in the normal way

Comment: I pull `FacilityGroup` from context, change its name and pass it to update method (both use the same context as it is supplied by DI)

Comment: If that's true, then you shouldn't need `DataContext.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;` at all since the entry is already in modified state

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue, it was because `AutoMapper`. My collection was mapped like this:

```
.ForMember(x => x.Facilities, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
```

changing it to:

```
.ForMember(x => x.Facilities, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

has solved the issue